# Error sum of square for OLS estimator

Tags: regression, self-study, residuals, error

The error sum of squares is defined as:

$$ SSe(\beta)=(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)\tag{1}$$

I want to show that for the OLS estimator $\hat\beta$,

$$SSe(\beta)=SSres+(\beta-\hat\beta)'X'X(\beta-\hat\beta)\tag{2}$$

I know that $SSres=SSe(\hat\beta)$, but I don't understand how to reach equation $(2)$ from $(1)$.

Comment: Can you check your question?  In line 2, you end up with $(\beta-\beta)$ twice, which is identically zero.  I think I se what you want to do, but can you clarify?

Comment: It looks right to me, should be (beta - beta hat)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite $y$ as $y=X\hat{\beta}+\epsilon$. Note that, here $\hat{\beta}$ represents estimated parameters and $\epsilon$ is the residual term.

Then, Eq. (1) becomes:
\begin{equation}
SSE(\beta)=(X\hat{\beta}+\epsilon-X\beta)^T(X\hat{\beta}+\epsilon-X\beta)\\
=(X(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+\epsilon)^T
(X(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+\epsilon)\\
=((\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^T+\epsilon^T)(X(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+\epsilon)\\
=(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+\epsilon^T\epsilon\\
=(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^TX^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+SSE(\hat{\beta})
\end{equation}